# Dependency injection failure in ASP.NET Core RC2

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I am unable to start up my asp.net core application after trying to port it to 1.0 RC2  from 1.0 RC1.  The startup error I get is this:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.Exception: Could not resolve a service of type 'Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.IConfiguration' for the parameter 'configuration' of method 'Configure' on type 'MYCOMPANY.MYTHING.Api.Startup'.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Startup.ConfigureBuilder.Invoke(Object instance, IApplicationBuilder builder)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost.BuildApplication()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.WebHostBuilder.Build()
   at MYCOMPANY.MYTHING.Api.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

I can't figure out how this is supposed to work.

The parts I do understand are:

- My startup.cs code looks correct to me, in Startup(IHostingEnvironment env) I create a ConfigurationBuilder and set Startup.Configuration equal to builder.Build(). The ConfigureServices method is also reached and Configuration object exists there.
- When the host.Run() code is reached in Program.cs, I get a crash.
- Configure(app,env,loggerFactory,configuration,respository...) method is NEVER reached.
- In RC1 there used to be a line like this:

  ```
  services.AddInstance<IConfiguration>(Configuration);
  ```
- In RC2 that doesn't exist anymore in a new application (I am reading a new application which works and trying to compare line by line).

I have been looking for how to make this work, and how to understand dependency injection of the IConfigurationRoot, but I don't see any attribute or code that seems to be responsible for this injection.

Update: It seems that I was using some strange pattern in my RC1 code that is no longer supported in RC2.  After I removed some additional parameters from my Configure() method it was once again invoked by the .net core startup code.

Comment: I'd like to see the Configure method of your Startup, note that services.AddInstance changed to .AddSingleton for rc2, but you should not need to inject IConfiguration into the Configure method, it should be persisted as a property in Startup contstructor, then you can access the property in Configure method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you have already fixed the issue, but the restriction with respect to the configure method is not as hard and fast as you suggest.

The restriction is you must have a public, instance or static method named `ConfigureDevelopment`, where *Development* is the environment name, or a method named `Configure`, which will be used if an environment specific configure method does not exist.

Obviously, you shouldn't need to inject your `IConfiguration` in to the `Configure` method as it will be set on your `Startup` class, but if you need something else injected (and you've configured it in `ConfigureServices` then you can do so. For example, the following would be perfectly valid.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<ISuperSecretClass, SuperSecretClass>();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, ISuperSecretClass instance)
{
   //do something with instance
}
```

For reference, I checked in [the StartupLoader source](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting/Startup/StartupLoader.cs) for the `Configure` restrictions.

Comment: I did have one, but it had extra "ISomething" parameters, and this seemed to prevent asp.net core from finding and invoking it. This answer is great because I didn't know about "ConfigureDevelopment".

Answer (score 3):

If you want to inject `Configuration` instance you can do:

```
services.AddSingleton((provider)=>
{
     return Configuration;
});
```

Comment: Normally this is not required. I think the problem is that you can build and compile a Startup.Configure() method which due to invalid signature is NEVER invoked, and this results in a broken .net core application with no warnings, just a runtime failure.